# XUL not referencing javascript file

Tags: javascript, xul, xulrunner

My XUL application has an external javascript file which defines some functions.  These functions were previously working, but now I can't call any of these functions from within the .xul file.  Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Here's the chrome.manifest file

```
content mac chrome/content/
skin    mac classic/1.0 chrome/skin/
```

Here's the very top of my main.xul file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://mac/skin/main.css" type="text/css"?>

<window id="mac-window" 
    title="MAC" 
    persist="screenX screenY width height sizemode"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome://mac/content/main.js"/>
```

Note that the css file referenced at the top of the file works fine.  Also, I've tried changing the "text/javascript" to "application/x-javascript" with no effect.

Here's the entire contents of the javascript file:

```
function exit() {
    window.close();
}

function toggle_toolbar(menuitem, toolbar) {

    switch (menuitem.getAttribute("checked"))
    {
    case "true":
        menuitem.setAttribute("checked", "false");
        toolbar.hidden = true;
        break;
    case "false";
        menuitem.setAttribute("checked", "true");
        toolbar.hidden = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

These functions get called like this:

```
<commandset id="cmdset-file">
    <command id="cmd-toolbar" oncommand="toggle_toolbar(document.getElementById('view-popup-toolbar'), document.getElementById('the-toolbar'));"/>
    <command id="cmd-exit" oncommand="exit();"/>
</commandset>
```

And two menuitems have the command attribute set to the id of these two commands.

Javascript put inline in the XUL file work properly, but it seems as if the javascript file cannot be referenced.  This worked perfectly fine earlier today.  Before this stopped working, I was experimenting with some javascript to hide/un-hide some tabboxes, but I'm not sure if that's related or not.

Does anyone see why my javascript file has stopped working?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For clarification, I'm using XULRunner.  Also, attempting to call one of the javascript functions from within script tags in the .xul document doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the Error Console - for a XULRunner app you can access it by specifying the `-jsconsole` command line flag. You will see this message:

> Exception: missing : after case label

Referring to this line:

```
case "false";
```

There should be a colon at the end of this line, not a semicolon. Your JavaScript file has a syntax error and that's why it doesn't load.